# Why isn't this problem in Real and Complex Analysis really easy?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

In Real and Complex Analysis, Walter Rudin proposes the following problem:

> Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of continuous functions in $[0,1]$ with $0\leq f_n\leq 1$ and such that for all $x\in [0,1]$, $f_n(x)\to 0$. Show that 
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 f_n(x)\:\mathrm{d}x=0.$$
>   Also try to prove this without using anything from Lebesgue's theory. (This exercice is meant to show how powerful Lebesgue's theory is.)

(This is my translation since I own the french version of the book.)

Since Rudin does this remark in the exercice, it seems to me that this ought to be a hard problem to do without Lebesgue's machinery. However, I thought about the following solution:

> Since $[0,1]$ is compact and $f_n\to 0$ pointwise, we have that $f_n\to 0$ uniformly. Then
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 f_n(x)\:\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^1\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\:\mathrm{d}x=0.$$

Is this wrong? If so, why?

Comment: To wit, how would you use Lebesgue integration to show it?

Comment: The sequence does not necessarily converge uniformly.

Comment: "Since $[0,1]$ is compact and $f_n\to 0$ pointwise, we have that $f_n\to0$ uniformly." ... By a result due to *Everett None*. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since $[0,1]$ is compact and $f_n \to 0$ pointwise, we have that $f_n \to 0$ uniformly.

That is incorrect. Choose any function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ that is equal to zero both in $0$ and $1$, but that is non-zero somewhere in $(0,1)$ (e.g., a triangle with vertices on $0$ and $1$).

Now, define $f_n:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ by putting 
$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} f(nx) &\mbox{$0 \leq x \leq 1/n$}; \\
0 &1/n \leq x \leq 1.
\end{cases}$$
This clearly goes pointwise to $0$ but does not converge uniformly.

---

You may have [Dini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem) in mind, but that requires the sequence to be monotone.